# Github: no jobs were run

Tags: python, android, kivy, github-actions, buildozer

i'm new to github and was making a python kivy app, it's just a basic calculator program. In .github/workflows/build.yml i pasted this:

```yaml
name: Build
on:
  push:

jobs:
# Build job. Builds app for Android with Buildozer
build-android:
  name: Build for Android
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build with Buildozer
      uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
      id: buildozer
      with:
        workdir: <specify the directory of the app no don't mention this the app files are in root directory>
        buildozer_version: stable

    - name: Upload artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: package
        path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```

In very small tests it worked just fine (4 times) but this time it says "Failure: no jobs were run"

Can explain why it happens?

Comment: How is your file indentation? Is your `build-android` field at the same level as the `jobs` field?

Comment: Yes, i tried indenting it into jobs field, but same results

Comment: Is it a public repo so you can share the workflow file?

Comment: It was public, but i made it private thinking that's the problem. I could make it public.

Comment: If it's not a problem for you to share it, it will make it easier to test forking your repository to investigate the issue.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/Thirtek/Kivy_calculator

Comment: It was indeed an indentation problem, I opened the PR here: https://github.com/Thirtek/Kivy_calculator/pull/1 and add an explanation as official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `build-android` job is at the same level that the `jobs` field, therefore it isn't recognized as part of the jobs list.

You can see it directly on Github if you try to edit the file on the GUI, it will return that the `jobs` field can't be null (because the interpreter didn't find any value in it).

[image]

After correcting it, I observed the workflow was running, but your action seems to have an issue with the `pip version` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/Kivy_calculator/runs/4116828841?check_suite_focus=true)). Resolving this other problem will probably let you run the workflow as expected.